# Issue in reverse polish notation task in C++

Tags: c++

The program analyzes the entered expression, converts it into reverse Polish notation and calculates the result.My program works correctly with expressions without brackets, but if I use an expression with brackets, I get an error: "Op" was nullptr. I have no idea why as my Stack "Op" must be initialized.(I marked where the error occurs in the code).

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

struct Stack {
    char info;
    Stack* next;
} *begin;

int Prior(char);
Stack* InStack(Stack*, char);
Stack* OutStack(Stack*, char&);
double Result(char*);
double mas[201];

Stack* InStack(Stack* p, char in) {
    Stack* t = new Stack;
    t->info = in;
    t->next = p;
    return t;
}

Stack* OutStack(Stack* p, char& in) {
    Stack* t = p;
    in = p->info;
    p = p->next;

    delete t;
    return p;
}

int Prior(char a) {
    switch (a) {
    case '^': return 4;
    case '*': case '/': return 3;
    case '-': case '+': return 2;
    case '(': return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

double Result(char* str) {
    int i;
    char ss, ss1, ss2, ssR = 'z' + 1;
    double op1, op2, res = 0, mas[200];

    std::cout << "Input data:" << std::endl;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        ss = str[i];
        if (ss >= 'a' && ss <= 'z')
        {
            std::cout << ss << " = ";
            std::cin >> mas[int(ss)];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        ss = str[i];

        if (!(ss == '+' || ss == '-' || ss == '*' || ss == '/'))
        {
            begin = InStack(begin, ss);
        }
        else
        {
            begin = OutStack(begin, ss2);
            begin = OutStack(begin, ss1);
            op2 = mas[int(ss2)];
            op1 = mas[int(ss1)];

            switch (ss)
            {
            case'+':res = op1 + op2; break;
            case'-':res = op1 - op2; break;
            case'*':res = op1 * op2; break;
            case'/':res = op1 / op2; break;
            }

            mas[int(ssR)] = res;
            begin = InStack(begin, ssR);
            ssR++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    Stack* t, * Op = NULL;
    char a;
    char In[81], Out[81];
    int k = 0, l = 0;
   
    std::cout << "Input form: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> In;
    
    while (In[k] != '\0')
    {
        if (In[k] >= 'a' && In[k] <= 'z')
        {
            Out[l++] = In[k];
        }
        
        if (In[k] == '(')
        {
            Op == InStack(Op, In[k]);
        }

        if (In[k] == ')')
        {
            while ((Op->info) != '(') //ERROR HERE
            {
                Op = OutStack(Op, a);

                if (!Op)
                {
                    a = '\0';
                }

                Out[l++] = a;
            }
            t = Op;
            Op = Op->next;
            delete t;
        }

        if (In[k] == '+' || In[k] == '-' || In[k] == '*' || In[k] == '/')
        {
            while (Op != NULL && Prior(Op->info) >= Prior(In[k]))
            {
                Op = OutStack(Op, a);

                Out[l++] = a;
            }
            Op = InStack(Op, In[k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
   
    while (Op != NULL)
    {
        Op = OutStack(Op, a);
        Out[l++] = a;
    }
    
    Out[l] = '\0';
    std::cout << "\nPolish: " << Out << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nRes = " << Result(Out) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: seems like the perfect time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: pay attention to your compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/dME1jxnY3. What input causes your program to crash? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Programm srop when i input expression with brackets and press Enter: 'Input form:
a+(b*c)'

Comment: Then I see exception that Stack "Op" is nullpointer

Comment: after fixing the `==` typo your code doesn't crash with that input for me

Comment: Like this: (Op->info) == '(' ? It worked for me too, but the result is incorrect. I'm so confused.

Comment: No `Op == InStack(Op, In[k]);` should be `Op = InStack(Op, In[k]);`

Comment: Ohh, so stupid mistake. I thought on it to much. Thanks a lot!